# jQuery width getting wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the jquery method .width(). I have 4 different textarea that need to resize according to the size of a div that contains them, so I call the method .width() to get the actual width of the div (wich anyway is 100% of the window) but this method always get the wrong value even after wrapping everything in a $(window).ready().

Here is the CSS

```
#contCode{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
.codeArea{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    height:100%;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    resize: none;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div id="contCode">
    <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
    <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
    <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
    <div class="codeArea"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the script

```
$(window).ready(function (){
        var wi = $("#contCode").width(); 
        var wiTex;
        wiTex = (wi) / 4;
        $(".codeArea").width(wiTex);
    });
```

I have already tried with outerWidth and innerWith and got the same result.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: [It returns the correct size.](https://jsfiddle.net/89d8gaeq/) You're probably confused about why there's a line break after the 3rd textarea. `border` adds extra width to each `codeArea` that you aren't accounting for. Try `wiTex = ((wi) / 4) - 8;` Subtracting 8 accounts for 2 extra pixels per box.

Comment: @MikeC – except, subtracting 8 pixels [doesn't actually fix it](https://jsfiddle.net/89d8gaeq/1/).
See my answer below instead

Comment: @KevinJantzer Your answer is not wrong but [subtracting 8 pixels does work.](https://jsfiddle.net/89d8gaeq/2/) You were performing the subtraction on the wrong value.

Comment: @MikeC - That logic is not what you described "2 extra pixels per box" – You are subtracting 8 pixels from each box (=32) when the borders only account for 2 pixels each (=8)

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two issues. The first I knew about

1. You need to add `box-sizing: border-box` so that when you set the `width` of the boxes the border width is included. If you don't, a box set to `100px` with a `1px` border will actually be `102px` wide.
2. The second issue I found was with jQuery's `.width()` method. For some reason even when I told it manually to set to `.width('100px')` the boxes were being set to `112px`. I changed it to use vanilla JavaScript instead.

You can see from the demo below that the boxes align now.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  var wi = $("#contCode").width();
  var wiTex = (wi) / 4;

  document.querySelectorAll('.codeArea').forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.width = wiTex+'px'
  })
  
});
```

```css
#contCode {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
.codeArea {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  resize: none;
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contCode">
  <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
  <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
  <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
  <div class="codeArea">The result area</div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool! that actually did it! The part of the border i had tought about and I was just substracting the size of the border from the width, but using the vanilla JS... actually I feel a little stupid for not trying that, maybe I couldn't believe jQuery's width() wouldn't work... Anyway thanks!

Comment: @AntonioVicencio, did you checked my answer? check that css-only part. It is much simpler and faster. Moreover it works even on the resize window without any aditional work =) your approach, though, need some additions to work well when window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

just use this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var wi = $("#contCode").width(); 
    var wiTex;
    wiTex = (wi) / 4;
    $(".codeArea").width(wiTex - 7); //here is the trick =)
});
```

why i substruct 7 pixels? That's because of how css calculate width of an element.

In css, width equals `width + padding + border`. In your case, real width of element would be: `wiTex` + `5px of left padding` + `2 pixels of borders`

---

you can even remove `javascript` code and use this `css`:

```
.codeArea{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    height:100%;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    resize: none;
    width: calc(25% - 7px); /* magic =) */
}
```

You can [see](https://jsfiddle.net/9g214k35/) it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```css
    #contCode{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        float:left;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .codeArea{
        float: left;
        font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
        height:100%;
        width:22%; //Added this
        padding:5px 0 0 5px;
        margin: 0;
        border:1px solid #ccc; 
        color:#333; 
        resize: none;
        background-color:#eee;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="contCode">
       <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
       <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
       <textarea class="codeArea" placeholder="Put your code here"></textarea>
       <div class="codeArea">Hello World</div>
    </div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a line break after the 3rd textarea. Is it because of the CSS3 box-sizing Property? By default it is content-box,which only contains the content itself but not the padding. You need to change it to border-box;